# POST data on multiple pages

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to post data from a form on multiple pages, but the main action should still be "".
So after I click, it should refresh on the same page but the POST data would have also went to another `.php`. I need this because at the other .php file, a graph is created which is embedded back onto the original form page.

I've tried using hidden fields. I can also do `graph.php?var1=3&var2=3`, etc. but I rather not display it like that.

I'm not too familiar with javascript, but I feel like that would be the way to go?

Comment: Sounds like a job for AJAX! check out jQuery's ajax function http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I think you rather should invoke the "other .php that creates the graph" from the server script to which you post to.

Comment: @BErgi By invoke do you mean direct to graph.php?

Comment: Can't you write a function that creates the graph, and call the function on your main PHP page?

Comment: @Kacey I'm using jpgraph and you can't really have it as part of your main code. You have to call upon it from a <img scr> unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @trigun0x2: No, no redirection (although it would be possible to let the request jump around the scripts).  You should be able to call the graph-generating function directly from you main script as a subroutine.

Comment: @Bergi I see what you mean. The syntax for jpgraph is quite weird, and I don't fully comprehend it, but I will look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it sounds like you should do a jQuery .ajax call or use a XMLHTTPRequest.  Post to the URL's you need, and once you get the results back, reload the page.

```
var i = 0
var pages = 3
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'value1', $('form input').val() );
fd.append( 'value2', $('form textarea').val() );

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/page1.php',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    i++;
    captureFunction();
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/page2.php',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    i++;
    captureFunction();
  }
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/page3.php',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
    i++;
    captureFunction();
  }
});

var captureFunction = function() {
  if(i != pages) return;
  location.reload()
}
```

I don't think this will work out of the box, but will be a good starting place for you to start hacking at.

Comment: No, actually it's not a javascript job.

Comment: When we're talking about a webpage, almost everything is a JavaScript job.

Comment: @Bergi you COULD do this with just php but why would you when it's so easy to just use ajax? all OP wants to do is refresh the page after sending some data to a php script...

Comment: @Stack_Admin_Rage little do yo know, I own example.com and my pages are named page1, 2, 3.php

Comment: Of course lots of things *can* be done today with JS, and some of them pretty easy due to powerful libraries, but that does not mean they *should*. In this case, they shouldn't (for [various reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)). If you really were the "everything is JS"-guy, you would recommend the OP not to POST the data at all but generate the graph dynamically in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `PHP`

Curl the POST request to each desired page when the page reloads.

e.g.

```
class Asynchronous {

    public function add($url, $params)
    {
        foreach ($params as $key => &$val) {
          if (is_array($val)) $val = implode(',', $val);
            $post_params[] = $key.'='.urlencode($val);
        }
        $post_string = implode('&', $post_params);

        $parts=parse_url($url);

        $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'], 
            isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80, 
            $errno, $errstr, 30);

        $out = "POST ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
        $out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
        $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        if (isset($post_string)) $out.= $post_string;

        fwrite($fp, $out);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```