# PHP post data to two different pages

Tags: php, jquery

How to Post same data to 2 pages in PHP, I need to select data from database in index.php and load_page.php

I try to do this:

```
<a href="index.php?cat=Gadgets && pag/load_data.php?cat=Gadgets" title="Common">
```

thanks

Comment: This won't work. Syntactically it makes no sense, and in any case you can only load one page at a time. Do everything you need in one page. If the PHP code you need is in a different page, perhaps you should look at converting it to functions and using `include` or `require` to make it available.

Comment: Why would you post the same data to two pages? Just take the response from one?

Comment: thanks, what if i send data from index to load_data using jquery?

Comment: Take a look at these http://stackoverflow.com/a/14780787/689579 (jQuery/Ajax) and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14781035/689579 (php) answers

Comment: Send the data to a central processing page and work with the data from there. <a href="process.php?cat=Gadgets" title="Common"> Then use include to include the results on your index page.

Comment: the second page is for pagination

Comment: Pagination on same index page? or what?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data to 2 different pages without redirecting the user through 2 pages you should have a look at AJAX with jQuery

If you want to open 2 pages with GET data you can easily do that with jQuery. Have jQuery listen to user clicks on the link and open a new tab.

Something like (not tested)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#link').bind('click', function(){

    window.open(url2, '_blank');
 });

});

</script>

<a href='mypage.php?data=bla&data2=bleh' id='link'>GO</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not make a huge amount of sense to send the same data to 2 different pages, however if it must be done I can think of 2 immediate options.

1. Use jQuery Ajax and make 2 separate requests - as previously suggested
2. Use cURL to make 2 post requests.

Below is an "untested" cURL option

```
<?php

## Data - from form or other source.
$data = array(
    "name"      => "c.bavota",
    "website"   => "http://bavotasan.com",
    "twitterID" => "bavotasan"
);

## Send data to 1 or more pages and collect responses.
$response_from_page1 = post_to_url("http://yoursite.com/page1.php", $data);
$response_from_page2 = post_to_url("http://yoursite.com/page2.php", $data);


## Function to make the POST requests.
function post_to_url($url, $data) {
    $fields = '';
    foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
    $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
    }
rtrim($fields, '&');

$post = curl_init();
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($post);
curl_close($post);
return $result;
}
?>
```

Each of your pages would return a text string, maybe something like true or false, depending on the exact application.

This is a slightly amended code from another tutorial.

**Source:** http://bavotasan.com/2011/post-url-using-curl-php/

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                    $.urlParam = function(name){
                     var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
                    if (!results) { return 0; }
                    return results[1] || 0;
                        }

                function loading_show(){
                    $('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
                }
                function loading_hide(){
                    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
                }                
                function loadData(page){
                    loading_show(); 
                    caty = $.urlParam('cat');
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "pagination/load_data.php",
                        data: {page: page, cat:  caty},
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                            $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                            {
                                loading_hide();
                                $("#container").html(msg);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
                $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                    var page = $(this).attr('p');
                    loadData(page);

                });           
                $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                    var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                    var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                    if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                        loadData(page);
                    }else{
                        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                        $('.goto').val("").focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                });
            });
        </script>
```

where cat:  caty was gotten from URL `caty = $.urlParam('cat');` using this function

```
 $.urlParam = function(name){
                         var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
                        if (!results) { return 0; }
                        return results[1] || 0;
                            }
```

and `page` is the `page` data of pagination sent from the same page `index.php`

both `page` (gotten from index.php) and `caty` gotten (from another page via link click), will be sent to script pagination in `pagination/load_data.php`.

in this case I can filter data to make pagination based on category and number/page choose.

Said